Handling with tabularx and tikzpicture
The goal is

Generate a centerd-aligned single cell tabularx large as document width
Insert a tikzipicture

MWE:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,tabularx}                                  

\begin{document}
\minipage{\textwidth}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c}
        \toprule
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[fill=none](0,0) circle (1.0) node [blue,yshift=-1.5cm] {Circle};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\endminipage
\end{document}

Result: tikzimage is left-aligned instead of center-aligned


Why a single cell table?

what is the point of a single cell table? Especially a tabularx one does nothing useful at all you just force latex to do multiple trial runs adjusting the width for linebreaking within the column when there is no possible linebreak that can happen as you have a single unbreakable picture.

I don't understand what use a single-cell table should serve, but if you want your tabularx to adjust to the text width, use (at least) one X column:
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}   

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
        \toprule
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[fill=none](0,0) circle (1.0) node [blue,yshift=-1.5cm] {Circle};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}


If you really want to use a table, a normal tabular would be much easier:
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{w{c}{\linewidth}}
        \toprule
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[fill=none](0,0) circle (1.0) node [blue,yshift=-1.5cm] {Circle};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}

